# MVC 5: Property Attribute error persists after fixed & removed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, memory-management, properties, attributes

I had an error caused by `length` counting on an `int`

Error:

```
[Required()]
[Display(Name = "Telefonnummer")]
[StringLength(12)]
public int UserPhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

After removing the `[StringLength(12)]` row completely. The validation attribute still seems to exist in memory and is still generating errors for me.

**Error on row 78:**

> Error:  The property 'UserPhoneNumber' is not a String or Byte array.
> Length can only be configured for String and Byte array properties.
>
> Line 76: // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
>
> Line 77: // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout,
> change to shouldLockout: true
>
> Line 78: var result = await
> SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password,
> model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
>
> Line 79: switch (result)

How do I refresh my applications Entity Framework? I have tried rebooting my computer and saving project, running application, update-database, add-migration, restarting Visual Studio.

Database is offline entity framework.

TL; Removed validation is still haunting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Had anoter property with the bloody [StringLength(12)].
My bad

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to Remove StringLength Attribure from your model. If your are getting same error try to create new Model/View and try again.

Comment: I cant recreate the whole `AccountViewModels` ! There is no way to re-scaffold it!

But I have removed the StringLength Attribute from my model. The error is still showing for no reason at all